# Conditionally replacing string with Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

In a node.js server I need to convert URL addresses using JavaScript as follows:

Example 1:

```
hostA/blah/dir1/name/id.js?a=b --> name.hostC/dir2.js?guid=id&a=b
```

Example 2:

```
hostB/dir1/name/id.js --> name.hostC/dir2.js?guid=id
```

The conversion is done with `string.replace` using regular expressions detailed inside a configuration file.

So far I have:

```
url.replace(/.*\\/dir1\\/(.*)\\/\\(d{2})\\.js?:(?=\?)(.*)/, "$1.hostC\/dir2.js?guid=$2");
```

The replacing string specifies `?guid=id`.  How do I alter the expression or the replacing string so that `&originalQueryString` (note the ampersand) will be added in case of example 1 and nothing added in case of example 2?

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/fJ7oW9/1) what you're looking for?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub In the first test case there, it needs to change the second `?` to a `&` (hence the difficulty).

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your examples:

```
text.replace(/.*?\/dir1\/([^\/]+)\/(.*?)\.js\??(.*)/i, "$1.hostC/dir2.js?guid=$2&$3").replace(/&$/, "")
```

You can change the regex options to include 'g' or 'm', if called for in your implementation.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, but this is what I ended up doing since it looks like a single expression to do what I want is too complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like

```
/([^/]+)\/([^./]+)\.js(?:\?(.*))?$/
```

**Example**

```
> "hostA/blah/dir1/name/id.js".replace(/([^/]+)\/([^./]+)\.js(?:\?(.*))?$/, "$1.hostC/dir2.js?guid=$2&$3")
< "hostA/blah/dir1/name.hostC/dir2.js?guid=id&"

> "hostA/blah/dir1/name/id.js?a=b".replace(/([^/]+)\/([^./]+)\.js(?:\?
(.*))?$/, "$1.hostC/dir2.js?guid=$2&$3")
< "hostA/blah/dir1/name.hostC/dir2.js?guid=id&a=b"
```

---

If the trailing `&` is a problem, you can break the regex into two statements,

```
< "hostA/blah/dir1/name/id.js".replace(/([^/]+)\/([^./]+)\.js$/, "$1.hostC/dir2.js?guid=$2")
> "hostA/blah/dir1/name.hostC/dir2.js?guid=id"

> "hostA/blah/dir1/name/id.js?a=b".replace(/([^/]+)\/([^./]+)\.js(?:\?(.*))$/, "$1.hostC/dir2.js?guid=$2&$3")
< "hostA/blah/dir1/name.hostC/dir2.js?guid=id&a=b"
```

Comment: They don't want a trailing `&` in the url. *nothing added in case of example 2*

Comment: What about `hostA/blah/dir1/name/id.js?a=b?b=c` ?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I assume that is not a valid url

Comment: The removal of the trailing `&` is quite complex to write in a single regex, because it is a new character inserted which you cannot capture from the input string, but have to be derived.

Comment: I would suggest a simple if statement that removes any trailing `&` if it is there. `if (url.charAt(url.length - 1) === "&") url = url.substr(0, url.length - 1);`

Comment: @4castle The expression and replacement string are on a config file. My code only performs a simple replace, and cannot have any knowledge of the expressions.

Comment: Of course I want to avoid the trailing `&`. It would have been easy otherwise.